# Best way to code this...(simple code, many buttons)

Tags: iphone, coding-style, system

I have a system for user to buy products. Their are many different products and it equates to around 80 buttons on a ipad screen. It is basic, they just have the product name on the buttons.

I started off the coding for one button

```
NSString *PriceString = TextView.text;
NSString *Final = [PriceString stringByAppendingString:@"\n Clothes Item 1   £20.00"];
TextView.text = Final;
TotalPrice += 20;
```

All this app needs to do is generate a text file with the name and price and then add the price to the total. I can do this however i dont fancy having 80 ibactions. So what would be the best way i could do this in the shortest amount of time and not with 80 separate IBactions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't want to add this as an answer, because I have to less time to describe it further. This is a case where I would use a UITableView. Take a look into it. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one `IBAction` method that examines the `tag` attribute of the `sender` (the buttons). Assign the method as the action for each button (on say, touch down). Give each button a unique tag, say the index into the array (for example) from which the button label/price came from.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;
    int tag = b.tag;
    // Use tag to know which button was pressed
    ...
}
```

So your logic for pressing a button is in one method, and the button itself has a tag that uniquely identifies it.

Comment: Thanks very much for the fast Reply, I will quickly try something like that out now.

Comment: Thanks Very much for this! I just tried it out and it works great! . I was unaware you could retrieve a buttons tag through a IBAction(using sender) and this has really helped me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Think about creating UIButton subclass and store a product button "attached" to inside button itself - that way you can have 1 action for all buttons and in action handler get product being purchased from the button that sends an action.

You'll have interface similar to:

```
@interface MyProductButton : UIButton{
   Product *product;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Product *product;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame product:(Product*)product;
...
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm going to quickly try out a few ways listed here and see which ones works best! Ill post my results here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create the buttons in code rather than using Interface Builder. And rather than having a method for each button, attach the data to the button, then use a single action method for every button. You could either subclass UIButton and add a data property, or use UIView's built-in tag property if all you need to store is a single integer (say, an array index).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have spent a long while making it look good in interface builder so don't really want to have change it all now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Interface Builder isn't an all or nothing choice. You can do everything except the buttons in IB, then add the buttons with code in your view controller's `-viewDidLoad` method.